# How to correctly setup google one top sign In with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I try to develop an email app. And my very first phase is to be able to have users to sign in their Gmail and get the data (which I am not even sure if I am on the right approach), However, I am stuck on the authentication part.

The following is what I get after I follow the instructions on Firebase and google one-tap documents with some modification
GSignIn.kt

```
class GSignIn : AppCompatActivity() {

     private lateinit var oneTapClient: SignInClient
     private lateinit var signInRequest: BeginSignInRequest
     private val REQ_ONE_TAP = 2  // Can be any integer unique to the Activity
     private var showOneTapUI = true
     private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth


     override fun onStart() {
          super.onStart()
          // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
          var currentUser = auth.currentUser
//          updateUI(currentUser);
     }


     override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

          when (requestCode) {
               REQ_ONE_TAP -> {
                    try {
                         val credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data)
                         val idToken = credential.googleIdToken
                         when {
                              idToken != null -> {
                                   // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                                   // with Firebase.
                                   Log.d(TAG, "Got ID token.")
                              }
                              else -> {
                                   // Shouldn't happen.
                                   Log.d(TAG, "No ID token!")
                              }
                         }
                    } catch (e: ApiException) {
                         // ...
                    }
               }
          }

          val googleCredential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data)
          val idToken = googleCredential.googleIdToken

          when {
               idToken != null -> {
                    // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                    // with Firebase.
                    val firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
                    auth.signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential)
                         .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                              if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                   // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                   Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                                   val user = auth.currentUser
//                                   updateUI(user)
                              } else {
                                   // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                   Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
//                                   updateUI(null)
                              }
                         }
               }
               else -> {
                    // Shouldn't happen.
                    Log.d(TAG, "No ID token!")
               }
          }

     }

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

          // Initialize Firebase Auth
          auth = Firebase.auth

          oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this)


          signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
               .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
                    BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                         .setSupported(true)
                         // Your server's client ID, not your Android client ID.
                         .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.your_web_client_id))
                         // Only show accounts previously used to sign in.
                         .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
                         .build()
               )
               .build()

          // One Tap Sign-In
          oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
               .addOnSuccessListener(this) { result ->
                    try {
                         startIntentSenderForResult(
                              result.pendingIntent.intentSender, REQ_ONE_TAP,
                              null, 0, 0, 0, null
                         )
                    } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                         Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start One Tap UI: ${e.localizedMessage}")
                    }
               }
               .addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
                    // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
                    // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                    Log.d(TAG, e.localizedMessage)
               }
          }

}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Aiko_mailTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                   modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    SignInButton(onClick = {
                        val intent = Intent(this, GSignIn::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)

                    })

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SignInButton(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp),
    ) {
        Text(text = "Sign In")
    }
}
```

This is my very first andorid app project, also my first time using Kotlin. I have sturggle with this for 2 months now. will be really appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: I just want to sign in to google through a button. And that's what I hope the code does.
I made the sign-in activity, and try to call it through a button. However, it causes 
"android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.aiko_mail/com.example.aiko_mail.engine.services.FireGSignIn}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?"

Comment: Anyway, I think what I did is pretty brutal. I do not fully understand the mechanism and how the things that work on android development with kotlin.
I will check your article, and try it out. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why did you delete this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75862481/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-when-implementing-fir)?

Comment: Because I solve this issue.
But I have a new issue now.

Comment: I just commented on your new question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the following error:

> "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.aiko_mail/com.example.aiko_mail.engine.services.FireGSignIn}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Because you did not declare `FireGSignIn` activity inside your AndroidManifest file. When you create a new activity, it's mandatory to be added inside AndroidManifest .xml file like this:

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.aiko_mail.engine.services.FireGSignIn"/>
```