# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin when implementing Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I was trying to implementing google sign in by following https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d

I have encouter the this

```
.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.6.0/a7257339a052df0f91433cf9651231bbb802b502/annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

I tried to change the kotlin version to 1.6.0 in the gradle, but still didn not work

project level

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.1.1'
        gradle_version = '7.3.0'
        kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
        google_services_version = '4.3.14'
        compose_bom_version = '2022.11.00'
        compose_version = '1.3.2'
        hilt_version = '2.44.2'
        hilt_navigation_compose_version = '1.0.0'
        firebase_bom_version = '31.0.3'
        play_services_version = '1.6.4'
        play_services_auth_version = '20.3.0'
        accompanist_version = '0.27.0'
        coil_compose_version = '2.2.2'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44.2"
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app level

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.app'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        viewBinding true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.1'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    //AndroidX
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1")
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"


    //compose
    implementation platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:$compose_bom_version")
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material"
    //Navigation Compose
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:$hilt_navigation_compose_version"

    //material
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0'

    //firebase
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebase_bom_version")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx"

    //Play Services
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:$play_services_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$play_services_auth_version"

    //Accompanist
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:$accompanist_version"
    //Coil
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:$coil_compose_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'


    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.34.1'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev20220404-2.0.0'
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.0.1")


    //Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
}
```

what else can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: nvm, I solve this question by setting
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.4'
    }

which is the latest version

Comment: ^ Did not work for me, and I'm not using Compose in my project directly.